# sort array with many conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

here is my case I am trying to sort an array with two name and crop equal true 
I am using lodash sortBy method

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy

it working just fine with sorting string but not working with boolean filed

here is my code

```
 const unsortedArray = [
      { name: "mina", lastName: "a", crop: false },
      { name: "aaa", lastName: "fa", crop: true },
      { name: "mina", lastName: "a", crop: true }
    ];
    console.log("un sorted array ", unsortedArray);
    console.log(
      " sorted array ",
      _.sortBy(unsortedArray , ["name" ,"crop"])
    );
```

Comment: It does work. The crop field is being treated as a string and it's being sorted in alphabetical order. How do you want it?

Comment: I need to sort against its boolean value mean true goes up, false goes down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
_.orderBy(unsortedArray , ["name" ,"crop"], ["asc", "desc"]);
```

Comment: Glad that it helped :)